# Watin : Open Windows form in watin

Tags: c#, watin

i have a link that when we click will produce a windows form that prompt us to download.Is there a way using watin for us to attach to this form and click the button?Can someone please direct me to the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by saying, that clicking a linkd produces a windows form? Isn't it just a separate IE window, probably created by js `window.open`? If so, then you need to create separate WatiN `IE` instance by attaching to that window. For example, if you want to control internet explorer window with title "My popup", you can do it that way:

```
var popup = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("My popup"))
```

You can find IE windows using constraints created using: `Find.ByUrl`, `Find.ByUri`, `Find.By("hwnd", windowHandle)` and mentioned `Find.ByTitle`.